# Top bar resized and overflowing on reputation change

Tags: bug, design, top-bar, responsive-design

In the normal case I don't see reputation points on the top bar on my Android phone:

> [image]

But it seems that after a positive reputation points change (green indicator on achievement icon) the top bar size is changed (overlapped the screen) and the total reputation points is appearing on the top bar:

> [image]

In the following case the help button (?) disappeared from the top bar:

> [image]